# C++17 Hexidecimal floating point literal single precision suffix conflict?

Tags: c++, floating-point, hex, c++17, literals

I was looking at the C++17 spec for floating point literals and found a problem.  How do you tell the difference between the digit `F` and the suffix `F` for single precision?

For instance, does the literal `0x1p0F` translate to a double precision `32768.0L` or a single precision `1.0F`?

The spec says that the suffix is optional, and that no suffix indicates double precision, so, as written, there is a definite ambiguity.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A hex-float literal must use a `p` exponent. The exponent is defined using non-hexadecimal digits (a decimal integer that represents the exponent to be applied to 2). Therefore, it cannot contain "A-F" characters. So there is no ambiguity. `0x1p0F` has an exponent of "0", and is of type `float`.

Comment: Ah, didn't catch the part about the exponent being decimal.  Definitely confusing.